# Who denounced Alexander Schmorell?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

[Alexander Schmorell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Schmorell) was a member of the anti nazi movement The [White Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Rose). In his entry in Wikipedia it is stated that he was caught by the Gestapo after being recognized by an old girlfriend while fleeing and having to hide from an airplane attack.

However the linked reference does not seem to contain this information. I was wondering if more information could ve found on the subject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The transcript of Schmorell's second interrogation by the Gestapo on February 26, 1943 indicates a slightly different sequence of events. From an [English translation](https://whiterosehistory.com/1943/02/26/second-interrogation-of-alexander-schmorell/):

> I arrived at the Munich-Thalkirchen train station on February 24, 1943 around 10 p.m. and took the streetcar from there to Kurfürstenplatz. Once I arrived, I thought about Dr. Uppleger; she lives at Schönererplatz 2. I wanted to ask this woman if I could spend the night at her house. But before I could reach her property, I was surprised by an air raid alarm. I had no other choice than to look up Dr. Uppleger in the air raid shelter in the basement of her house. Once there, I asked her to come with me to the entrance, so I could speak with her alone. Unexpectedly, a man about 45 years old emerged from the air raid shelter wearing a railroad uniform. He came up to me and took me into custody. Although I tried to escape, several men running by in uniforms overpowered me and handed me over to the police.

Apparently unbeknownst to Schmorell, police appeals for his apprehension ran in newspapers on February 24 <sup>[1,2]</sup> and February 25 <sup>[3]</sup> offering a reward of RM 1000. These included a detailed physical description and a photo in some cases.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Völkischer Beobachter](https://www.universitaetsarchiv.uni-muenchen.de/bilder/monatsstueck/web_bilder_l/sdm_2013_02_0004_l.jpg)
<sup>2</sup> [Münchner Neueste Nachrichten](https://www.facebook.com/WeisseRoseStiftung/posts/2841587579227971/)
<sup>3</sup> [Salzburger Zeitung](https://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno?apm=0&aid=szt&datum=19430225&seite=5)